# Shiny DT datatable Make only certain columns editable by the user

Tags: r, shiny, dt

A simple app:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("blah"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            DT::DTOutput('ex_df')
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$ex_df <- DT::renderDT(data.frame(
        x = 1:10,
        y = 1,
        z = 11:20
    ), 
    
    selection = 'none', editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, rownames = FALSE,
    list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1,2)))
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this line: `disable = list(columns = c(1,2)` I intended to make the 1st and second column un editable. However, all columns seem to be editable:
[image]

How can I set it so that only the 3rd column is editable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation for `DT::datatable()`, the `editable` argument should be structured differently:

> This argument can also be a list of the form list(target = TARGET,
> disable = list(columns = INDICES)), where TARGET can be cell, row,
> column, or all, and INDICES is an integer vector of column indices.

Try `editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(1,2))`

Comment: Thanks I tried that, yet all the columns are still showing as editable

Answer (score 4):

You need to use 0 based indices to indicate the disabled columns. Try using `editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(0, 1))`